# Convergence of a sequence of Bernoulli variables.

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables

For $\lambda\in(0,1)$ consider the following sequence of Bernoulli random variables

$$
\mathbb{P}\left[B_n=1\right]=1-\frac{\lambda}{n},\quad \mathbb{P}\left[B_n=0\right]=\frac{\lambda}{n}.
$$

Now consider

$$
C_n = n\,\left(1-B_n\right).
$$

My initial guess was that $C_n\stackrel{L^1}{\rightarrow}\lambda$. Nevertheless

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\left|n\,\left(1-B_n\right)-\lambda\right|\right] = \frac{\lambda}{n}\,(n-\lambda)+(1-\frac{\lambda}{n})\,\lambda\rightarrow 2\,\lambda\neq 0.
$$

I am stucked with this very simple problem. Do the $C_n$'s converge somewhere (not necessarily in norm $L^1$) ?

Comment: Yes, (assuming $B_i$ are independent) $C_n$ converges to $0$ in probability but not in $L^1$ or $a.s$. Note that $E(C_n)=\lambda$.